# Tabhost not updating tabs

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I'm trying to have vertical tabs in a project, but I cannot get tabhost to work. I think I'm not getting in right from Java, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There are many examples only, but they seem to be outdated. It seems tabhost has changed a lot, so I'm not sure of the right syntax. This is my xml:

```
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" ...>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"...>
        <FrameLayout ...>
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:visibility="gone" .../>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical" ...>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_map"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler" .../>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_chat"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler" .../>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_player_stat"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler" ... />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_dest_card"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler" .../>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" ...>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:orientation="vertical" ...>

            <TextView
                android:text="This is tab 1" .../>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2" 
            android:orientation="vertical" ...>

            <TextView
                android:text="This is tab 2" ... />
        </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

And then on java I'm trying to do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
    }
```

Then the tabHandler

```
public void tabHandler(View target){
        button_map.setSelected(false);
        button_chat.setSelected(false);
        if(target.getId() == R.id.button_map){
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            button_map.setSelected(true);
        } else if(target.getId() == R.id.button_chat){
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            button_chat.setSelected(true);
        } 
        }
```

When I try to run this nothing happens when I clicked on the "tabs"(my buttons). The code is getting to the right place, but I think the findview() is getting the wrong tabHost. On the debugger I see that tabhost currentTab is set to -1 which is why I believe is it the wrong tabhost. I've also tried changing tabhost from "@android:id/tabhost to @+id/tabhost, but that throws an exception when using setup() which complains that it should be @android:id/tabhost. Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use TabHost in a new app to implement tabs.  [Use a ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) instead.

You can also use a Bottom Navigation View from the Android support library, if that meets your use case.  [Here is one relevant tutorial](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0).

Comment: Is there a reason why not to use tabHost? TabActivity is deprecated, but Tabhost is not. When I searched how to do tabs it seemed like a fairly common solution.

Comment: Correct, the TabHost class itself is not deprecated.  However, the most recent guidance from Google on how to implement tabbed navigation does not mention it (that is the first link that I provided).

Comment: Also, there is some information at https://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/older-implementation.html that talks about using TabHost if you need to support older versions of Android.  Do you have such a requirement?

Comment: Nope, I was just wondering as of why viewPager would be preferable.